# Do I need to use inversion after an opinion phrase?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, verb-usage

I have the phrase

> Ich wollte nie Drogen nehmen.

I want to put "Ich bin sicher" in front. Should the final sentence be:

> Ich bin sicher, ich wollte nie Drogen nehmen.

or

> Ich bin sicher, wollte ich nie Drogen nehmen.

Answer (score 11):

Same as in indirect speech: If you use "dass" to connect the sentences, the verb is moved to final position:

> Er sagte, *dass* er sehr hungrig *sei*.
>
> Ich glaube, *dass* ich heute nicht fertig *werde*.
>
> Ich bin sicher, *dass* ich nie Drogen nehmen *wollte*.

If the sentences are connected without "dass", the verb remains in v2 position:

> Er sagte, er *sei* sehr hungrig.
>
> Ich glaube, ich *werde* heute nicht fertig. / Ich glaube, heute *werde* ich nicht fertig.
>
> Ich bin sicher, ich *wollte* nie Drogen nehmen.

In both cases, moving the verb to the front position is impossible.